# ¿Como modificar y eliminar de dos tablas al mismo tiempos?

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Buenas Tardes, necesito de su ayuda, estoy tratando de eliminar y modificar de dos tablas al mismo tiempo anexo el codigo que estoy utilizando;
espero y puedan ayudarme ya que se me dificultando mucho realizarlo, se los agradecería :)....

Funciones.php

```
<?php
class revista{
    public function conecta($modo = "local"){
        $servername = "localhost";
        if ($modo == "local") {
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "revista";
        }elseif ($modo == "web") {
            $username = "";
            $password = "";
            $dbname = "";
        }

        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Error de conexión: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        return  $conn;
    }

    public function registro($no_revista, $colaboradores, $fecha_publicacion, $imagen, $archivo, $articulo, $autor){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO revista (no_revista, colaboradores, fecha_publicacion, imagen, archivo) 
    VALUES ('$no_revista', '$colaboradores', '$fecha_publicacion', '$imagen', '$archivo')";
    $consulta = $this->conecta()->query($sql);
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO articulos (articulo, autor) 
    VALUES ('$articulo', '$autor')";
    $consulta = $this->conecta()->query($sql1);
    }
}
?>
```

index.html

```
<section class="contenido">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h3 class="titulo1">Revistas</h3>
            <p class="descripcion">Dentro de está interfaz el administrador podrá consultar, actualizar y eliminar cada una de las revistras que se encuentran publicadas.</p>
            <hr><br>
        <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
               <th class="col-md-8 encabezados">NO. REVISTA</th>
               <th class="col-md-2 encabezados">MODIFICAR</th>
               <th class="col-md-2 encabezados">ELIMINAR</th>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td>Nombre de la revista</td>
                <td><center><a class="gb-thick-border1" href="editar.php?id_revista=<?php echo $row->id_revista; ?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></center>EDITAR</td>
                <td><center><a class="gb-thick-border1" href="borrar.php?id_revista=<?php echo $row->id_revista;?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></center>ELIMINAR</td>
              </tr>
              <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
          </table><br><br>
          <center><a class="gb-thick-border" href="index.php">Agregar una revista nueva</a></center>
        </div>      
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Espero de su ayuda, muchas gracias...

Comment: Y qué error te está tirando, o qué es lo que no resulta?

Answer (score 1):

Suponemos que tenemos dos Tablas en nuestra base de datos. Factura y Usuarios. Actualizaremos a la vez ambas tablas usando la sentencia `INNER JOIN` de SQL.

```
SELECT Factura.columName, Usuarios.columName
FROM Factura
INNER JOIN Usuarios ON Factura.columnName = Usuarios.columName;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`Inner Join` Devuelve únicamente aquellos registros/filas que tienen valores idénticos en los dos campos que se comparan para unir ambas tablas. Es decir aquellas que tienen elementos en las dos tablas, identificados éstos por el campo de relación.

Comment: La consulta para eliminar quedaría algo así @Tygreton?                                           public function eliminar(){
$sql = "DELETE revista.clave, articulos.clave FROM revista INNER JOIN articulos ON revista.clave = articulos.clave;"
$consulta = $this->conecta()->query($sql);
}

Comment: y como se mandaría llamar al botón o como identifica que eliminara?